# tx.gasprice gives wrong gas estimation

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas-price, gas-limit, gas-estimate

I am using tx.gasprice and block.basefee in my contract to calculate the used gas.

The problem is that I can't estimate the gas correctly or sometimes not at all when the contract uses `tx.gasprice;`.

By the way, I use `contract.estimateGas.refundTest(address);` to estimate the gas.

I called the same contract with the same function 3 times and everytime i got a different gas amount spent(see goerli.ethersscan) although i got the same `console.log(estimateGas)` from the estimateGas function.

my Questions:

1. why did it use different amounts of gas each time, I ran the same code 3 times so there should be no differences?
2. why does estimateGas show me the wrong amount of gas when I use tx.gasprice (Metamask can't calculate it correctly either)?
3. is there another way (I also tried web3.js -> same result) to calculate the esimtatedGas, because I need it for my main project and I don't want to do it manually for each transaction call?

---

```
const MetaButton = () => {

    const { ethereum } = window;


    const handleButtonClick = async () => {

        const accounts = await ethereum.request({
            method: "eth_requestAccounts"
        });

        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const walletAddress = accounts[0];   // first account in MetaMask
        const signer = provider.getSigner(walletAddress);

        console.log(provider);
        let web3 = new Web3(provider.provider);


        const officialTest = new ethers.Contract("0xb00692ddaDF2FD6B929C5694da87D684239E860D", abi3, signer);
        let gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
        let estimatedGas = await officialTest.estimateGas.refundTest("0x9132F0Ba64d799A664499CA4a30298365eA52408");
        console.log("estimatedGas: ", estimatedGas);
        console.log("gasPrice: ", gasPrice);
        console.log("both: ", gasPrice.toNumber() * estimatedGas.toNumber());
        const tx= await officialTest.refundTest("0x9132F0Ba64d799A664499CA4a30298365eA52408",{gasLimit: estimatedGas.toNumber()+42000});
        console.log("tx: ", tx);
        

    };
    return (
        <button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleButtonClick}>Connect
        </button>);
};

export default MetaButton;
```

---

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";

interface IWrapped {
    function withdraw(uint256 wad) external;
}
interface Gas {
    function getPrice() external;
}

contract gasTestContract {
    uint public gasprice;
    uint public basefee;
    uint public gas;

    address constant WCOIN = 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6;
    ISwapRouter public constant swapRouter =
        ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    uint public lastRefund;
    mapping(address=>uint256) balanceOf;

    function getPrice() external {
        gasprice = tx.gasprice;
    }

    function getFee() external {
        basefee = block.basefee;
    }

    function getGas() external{
        gas = gasleft();
    }

    function getAll() external {
        gas = gasleft();
        basefee = block.basefee;
        gasprice = tx.gasprice;
    }

    fallback() external payable {}

    function refundBack() external {
        gas = gasleft() + 22000;
        lastRefund = gas * tx.gasprice;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(lastRefund);
    }

    function refundTest(address _contract) external {
        gas = gasleft() + 22000;
        lastRefund = gas * tx.gasprice;
        Gas(_contract).getPrice();
    }

    function refund(uint amountInMaximum, IERC20 chosenToken) external payable{
        
        gas = gasleft() + 22000;

        lastRefund = gas * tx.gasprice;

        TransferHelper.safeApprove(
            address(chosenToken),
            address(swapRouter),
            amountInMaximum
        );

        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: address(chosenToken),
                tokenOut: WCOIN,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: lastRefund,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);


        IWrapped(WCOIN).withdraw(lastRefund);

        //gasprice = tx.gasprice;
        //basefee = block.basefee;

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(lastRefund);


    }
}
```

---

0x9e6b = 40555

[image]

---

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xc8d6950f19f66c5cb7df7d9ad118735d526a90703f949d7bc3d72301a3a7be83

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xf9a771719721c21b9ac94e2e49a2a97154a0b875f09c5c8aeddc74478e02569d

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x74d1cef579204fcc406d71f725b646d7ca3be5db0bc292fc4d3fa6416e7ec9e4